# Nautilus takes so long to open when I have a network folder mounted

Tags: gnome, nautilus

Im using Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 and nautilus takes a long to open when I have my NAS folders mounted on fstab.
When I open Nautilus as root, its open quickly.

What I have to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a network drive mounted to your computer, it means it has to update the status every time you open nautilus. Because the drive will appear in the left pane where your bookmarks are.

**My suggestion** will be to unmount the drive when not used, in order to prevent the time it takes to load it every time nautilus is open, OR
**you could** let a window with Nautilus stay open in the background all the time, so it wont take that long for it to load.

I am not rather sure if those suggestions will work out for you, but i guess so based on what i have experienced myself. However, if i am wrong about this, i am terribly sorry.